# Deploying .war containing JavaFX .jar to GlassFish NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: glassfish, javafx

My JavaFX application requires a class in another jar file.

Both are deployed as part of a war file

The JavaFX jar is not finding the my-xxx.class contained in WEB-INF/lib/MyJavaFXClient.jar

The contents of my war file are:

```
    images/
    META-INF/
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF/
    WEB-INF/lib/
    WEB-INF/lib/bin/glass.dll
    WEB-INF/lib/MyJavaFxClient.jar ( this is the jar my JavaFX app requires )
    WEB-INF/sun-web.xml
    WEB-INF/web.xml
    index.jsp 
    index.html
    MyJavaFxApp.jnlp
    MyJavaFxApp.jar  (my JavaFx app)
```

JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="MyJavaFxApp.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>App: TestDriver</title>
    <vendor>Demo</vendor>
    <description>JavaFX application test client</description>
    <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/testdriver/"/>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>

<security>
   <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" 
     href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-      i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
</resources>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-verbose:class
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <property name="javafx.verbose" value="true"/>
    <property name="java.library.path" value="WEB-INF/lib/bin"/>
    <jar href="MyJavaFxApp.jar" size="318607" download="eager" />
</resources>
<applet-desc  width="800" height="600" 
              main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  
              name="MyJavaFxApp" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
</applet-desc>
<jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" 
                  main-class="ui.client.MyJavaFXMain"  name="MyJavaFxApp" />
<update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: What does your JNLP file look like?

Comment: JNLP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="PRISMTestDriver.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>App: TestDriver</title>
    <vendor>Demo</vendor>
    <description>JavaFX application test client</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>      
   <all-permissions/>  
  </security>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>

Comment: JNLP continues...
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-verbose:class "  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <property name="javafx.verbose" value="true"/>
    <property name="java.library.path" value="WEB-INF/lib;WEB-INF/lib/bin"/>
    <jar href="PRISMTestDriver.jar" size="320828" download="eager" />
  </resources>

Comment: JNLP continues...
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="MyJavaFXApp" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="prism.ui.client.Main"  name="MyJavaFXAppDriver" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>

Comment: please post it in your question using code formatting

Comment: The external jar (e.g., MyJavaFxClient.ja) contains classes that are used by the fx main application (MyJavaFxApp).  I resolved my problem by adding external jar to the build.xml as a resource of the <fx:deploy> ant task.